# Manual json_encode syntax error

Tags: php

I have this code bellow:

```
 $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vieuxparis1");
 $mn = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM paris');
 $jsonval = array();
 while($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mn)):
 $json = array();
 $json["id"] = $get["ID"];
 $json["picture"] = $get["picture"];
 $json["name"] = $get["name"];
 $json["category"] = $get["category"];
 $json["address"] = $get["adress"];
 $json["about"] = $get["about"];
 $json["location"]=array(
     "latitude" => $get["latitude"],
     "longitude" => $get["longitude"]
       );
 $json["tags"]=array(
   "in",
   "aliqua",
   "voluptate"
 );
 $json["openings"]=array(
   "monday" => "10:00 - 22:00",
   "tuesday"=> "09:00 - 21:00",
   "wednesday"=> "09:00 - 21:00",
   "thursday"=> "09:00 - 21:00",
   "friday"=> "09:00 - 21:00",
   "saturday"=> "09:00 - 21:00",
   "sunday"=> "closed"
 );
 array_push($jsonval,$json);
 endwhile;
```

So, when i echo, i got this, with 2 times "latitude" and "longitude":

```
"about":"Ceci est un quartier parisien","latitude":"48.8405818","longitude":"2.286173299999973","location":["48.8405818","2.286173299999973"],
```

And I want exactly this:

```
"about": "Ceci est un quartier parisien",
"location": {"latitude": "48.861001",
             "longitude": "2.335876"
            },
```

Do you know how i should write my code??

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is the json_encode syntax error ?

Comment: I dont see how that code could possibly produce the output you say it is producing

Comment: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) works as expected (the text you posted as its "output" is just a fragment of its actual output). You build the array in a wrong way. Use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to inspect the content of the array before blaming `json_encode()`. Read more about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and about the [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment. I have already read this. I would think about it next time

Comment: Thanks guys, i've got the answer. It is 
    $json["about"] = $get["about"];
    $json["location"]=array(
    "latitude" => $get["latitude"],
    "longitude" => $get["longitude"]
    );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building your array in a wrong way. You are not setting associative keys, it is "just" an assignment:

```
$json = array(
$json["latitude"] = $get["latitude"]
)
```

The correct way of setting an associative keys with "=>" notation:

```
$array = array(
    'key' => 'value'
);

// or

$array['key'] = 'value';
```

Please try:

```
$json["about"] = $get["about"];
$json["location"]=array(
   "latitude" => $get["latitude"],
   "longitude" => $get["longitude"]
);
```

Comment: While the suggestion solves the problem, it would be useful for both the OP and for future readers to explain what's wrong in the original code and how your suggestion fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use array notation `=>` not  `=` `ASSIGNMENT operator`

```
$json["location"]=array(
   "latitude" => $get["latitude"],
   "longitude" => $get["longitude"]
);
```